# Passing value from Calendar Picker to textbox

Tags: html, date

Hi guys I am having trouble getting value from the calendar picker. 
I want to chose a date from the calendar (with id `Date_of_Birth`) and assign the date say `12/11/2013` to the textbox `txtDate`.

How do I do this? My code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

<form name="myForm" action="displayDate.html" method="post">

Date of Birth: < script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx?dateFormat=dd/mm/yy" name="Date_of_Birth" id="Date_of_Birth"></script><br>

           <input type="text" id="txtDate" name="txtDate"

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you did not include "http://www.snaphost.com/jquery/Calendar.aspx?dateFormat=dd/mm/yy" correctly. This script creates a calendar and does not work the way you want it to. From the code I could see this library uses jQueryUI.

Instead of using the aspx url, include the jQueryUI library separately:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" action="displayDate.html" method="post">

    Date of Birth: <input type="text" id="txtDate" name="txtDate"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

To bind a datepicker to the txtDate use:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#txtDate" ).datepicker();
  });
```

See the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2zdgz/